What does apply do in sapply function?
set.seed(2)
x <- round(rnorm(25, 50, 10))
z <- sample(1:5, 25, replace=T)
alpha <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 25, replace=T)
f <- factor(alpha)
s <- split(data.frame(x=x, z=z), f)
sapply(s, apply, 2, median)

Hi. This is my code, and I don't know what does "apply" do in sapply function.
I searched in R documentation with ?sapply, but I found nothing that I look for.
I just wanna know what does "apply" do in sapply function. Can anybody help please?

The apply computes the median of the columns (MARGIN=2) for each df in your list s. Check e.g. apply(mtcars, 2, median).

... aka double/nested loop.

The sapply line is the same as sapply(s, function(x) apply(x, 2, median)) so for each element of the list s it takes the median of every column.  1 as the second argument of apply means by row and 2 as we have here means by column.

apply calls a function (here median()) through the margin of an array.
It acts as a loop within the sapply loop.
The best way to way to understand it is to replace sapply and apply by nested for loops.
The above code does the same as your unique call to sapply and apply:
    mat <- matrix(numeric(6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("x", "z"), c("A", "B", "C")))
    df <- data.frame(mat)
    for (letter in names(s)) { # sapply equivalent: loop through the groups A, B and C
      splitted_data <- s[[letter]]
      for (col_name in names(splitted_data)) { # apply equivalent: call median for each column of each group
        df[col_name, letter] <- median(splitted_data[[col_name]])
      }
    } 
print(df)

